# Starvation of one of 2 streams in ConnectedStreams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

#### Background

We have 2 streams, let's call them `A` and `B`.
They produce elements `a` and `b` respectively.

Stream `A` produces elements at a slow rate (one every minute).

Stream `B` receives a single element once every 2 weeks. It uses a `flatMap` function which receives this element and generates ~2 million `b` elements in a loop:

(Java)

```
for (BElement value : valuesList) {
    out.collect(updatedTileMapVersion);
}
```

The `valueList` here contains ~2 million `b` elements

We connect those streams (`A` and `B`) using `connect`, key by some key and perform another `flatMap` on the connected stream:

```
streamA.connect(streamB).keyBy(AClass::someKey, BClass::someKey).flatMap(processConnectedStreams)
```

Each of the `b` elements has a different key, meaning there are ~2 million keys coming from the `B` stream.

#### The Problem

What we see is starvation. Even though there are `a` elements ready to be processed they are not processed in the `processConnectedStreams`.

#### Our tries to solve the issue

We tried to throttle stream `B` to 10 elements in a 1 second by performing a `Thread.sleep()` every 10 elements:

```
long totalSent = 0;
for (BElement value : valuesList) {
    totalSent++;
    out.collect(updatedTileMapVersion);
    if (totalSent % 10 == 0) {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

The `processConnectedStreams` is simulated to take 1 second with another `Thread.sleep()` and we have tried it with:
* Setting parallelism of 10 to all the pipeline - didn't work
* Setting parallelism of 15 to all the pipeline - did work

#### The question

We don't want to use all these resources since stream `B` is activated very rarely and for stream `A` elements having high parallelism is an overkill.
Is it possible to solve it without setting the parallelism to more than the number of `b` elements we send every second?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you shared the complete workflow topology. For example, you don't mention doing any keying or random partitioning of the data. If that's really the case, then Flink is going to pipeline multiple operations in one task, which can (depending on the topology) lead to the problem you're seeing.

If that's the case, then forcing partitioning prior to the `processConnectedStreams` can help, as then that operation will be reading from network buffers.

Comment: I've edited the question by adding the `keyBy` step after the `connect`.